# Announcement: New tag for questions related to self-driving vehicles

Tags: discussion, tags

I have created a new tag named: [self-driving](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/tags/self-driving/info) for accommodating all the self-driving tech related questions.

So, if you find any such questions, feel free to edit.

Also, if you have any tag-requests, do answer here, and we shall try to consider them.